# -ms-flexbox not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, flexbox

Firstly I wrote:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

and it was working for IE11, but then I realised that it's not working for IE8, so I added two more lines:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-pack: space-between;
```

and it's still not working for older version than IE11, why?

Comment: Probably because at the time IE8 was released, flexbox didn't even exist?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.planningforaliens.com/blog/2014/03/11/real-world-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because IE10- do not support flexbox. You can visit this [website](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) to check whether the browser you need supports CSS property or not